# Bootstrap Accordion Not Closing

Tags: accordion, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a functioning Bootstrap 3.0 accordion that opens when you click one of the Main Links. The only issue is that if you click on a second Main Link, the first link does not collapse - they all just stay open.

Is there a way to make the other sections close, leaving only one open at a time?

HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- begin left nav -->
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="left-nav">
      <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
        <!-- group start -->
        <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
          <a class="accordion-toggle leftnav-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
          Main Link 1
          </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse"> <!-- add "in" to class to load acc section open -->
          <div class="accordion-inner">
          <div class="left-nav-section"><a href="product.html" class="leftnav-secondary">Product 1</a></div> <!-- add "selected-section" to add background color -->
          <div class="left-nav-section"><a href="product.html" class="leftnav-secondary">Product 2</a></div>
          <div class="left-nav-section"><a href="product.html" class="leftnav-secondary">Product 3</a></div>
          <div class="left-nav-section"><a href="product.html" class="leftnav-secondary">Product 4</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div> <!-- end group -->
        <!-- group start -->
        <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
          <a class="accordion-toggle leftnav-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
          Main Link 2
          </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
          <div class="accordion-inner">
          <div class="left-nav-section"><a href="product.html" class="leftnav-secondary">Link</a></div>
                       <div class="left-nav-section"><a href="product.html" class="leftnav-secondary">Link</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div> <!-- end group -->
        <!-- group start -->
        <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
          <a class="accordion-toggle leftnav-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree">
          Main Link 3
          </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body collapse">
          <div class="accordion-inner">
          <div class="left-nav-section"><a href="product.html" class="leftnav-secondary">Link</a></div>
                       <div class="left-nav-section"><a href="product.html" class="leftnav-secondary">Link</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div> <!-- end group -->
        <!-- group start -->
        <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
          <a class="accordion-toggle leftnav-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFour">
          Main Link 4
          </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFour" class="accordion-body collapse">
          <div class="accordion-inner">
          <div class="left-nav-section"><a href="product.html" class="leftnav-secondary">Link</a></div>
                       <div class="left-nav-section"><a href="product.html" class="leftnav-secondary">Link</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div> <!-- end group -->
        <!-- group start -->
        <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
          <a class="accordion-toggle leftnav-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseFive">
          Main Link 5
          </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFive" class="accordion-body collapse">
          <div class="accordion-inner">
          <div class="left-nav-section"><a href="product.html" class="leftnav-secondary">Link</a></div>
                       <div class="left-nav-section"><a href="product.html" class="leftnav-secondary">Link</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div> <!-- end group -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /left nav -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.left-nav {
  width:200px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 110%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color:#ff0;
   -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255) transparent;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99ffffff, endColorstr=#99ffffff);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99ffffff, endColorstr=#99ffffff)";
  overflow:hidden;
}

a.leftnav-primary:link { color:#363; text-decoration: none; }
a.leftnav-primary:visited { color:#363; text-decoration: none; }
a.leftnav-primary:hover { color:#6e2585; text-decoration: none; }
a.leftnav-primary:active { color:#363; text-decoration: underline; }

a.leftnav-secondary:link { color:#6c6f70; text-decoration: none; font-size: 90%; }
a.leftnav-secondary:visited { color:#6c6f70; text-decoration: none; font-size: 90%; }
a.leftnav-secondary:hover { color:#6e2585; text-decoration: none; font-size: 90%; }
a.leftnav-secondary:active { color:#6e2585; text-decoration: underline; font-size: 90%; }

.left-nav-section   { padding-left: 20px; }
.left-nav-section:hover { background-color: #eee; }
```

Here is my JS Fiddle with the working accordion:
http://jsfiddle.net/lorkel/pK7cA/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known Bootstrap issue: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10966

If you change your `accordion-group` to `panel` it will work (but may not have the desired style)

http://jsfiddle.net/pK7cA/1/

Hopefully it will be fixed in the near future so that it's not dependent on `panel` for use of `data-parent`.

Comment: Thanks Skelly. So there's no JS workaround to get the others to close at the moment?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to close others. If anyone came here in search just like me.

The way to do it is to maintain "data-parent" same as accordion's id.

if the parent is

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion123">
```

Then children must have :

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading" ... data-parent="#accordion123">
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  All panels inside this..
</div>
```

In our case, the problem was in HTML structure, as we had `<div id="accordion>` inside foreach loop. The fix is to use a single accordion for all the panels.